# Differentiating $x+y+a=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

If we consider the equation $$x+y+a=0\tag{1}$$ we get $$1+dy/dx+0=0\tag{2}$$  as the solution, if we differentiate. We have the reason for writing differentiation of $y$ as $dy/dx$ instead of zero. If we rewrite the equation $1$ we have, $y=-x-a$, we see that alphabet $y$ depends on $x$ which varies, so we consider $y$ as variable instead of constant. We can also rewrite the equation $1$ as $a=-x-y$, so even $a$ depends on x, won't it mean that we are required to write differentiation of $a$ as $da/dx$ instead of zero?

Comment: In all cases, $a$ is a constant, correct?

Comment: You can think of $a$ as a function of $x$ if you wish, but since $a$ is a constant, it would be a constant function of $x$ ... in which case $\frac{da}{dx}=0$.

Answer (score 1):

What Equation 1 says is that there is a function $y(x)$ which is implicitly defined by

$$x+y(x)+a=0$$
where a is a constant.

The fact you can write $a=-x-y(x)$ does NOT mean that $a$ depends on $x$. It could very well be the case (as it is) that the function $y(x)$ is such that $-x-y(x)=constant$, $\forall x$. Therefore, you cannot find $a$ from equation 1 (since it is already being used to define $y(x)$), but you must know what it is beforehand. If not mentioned explicitly, though, then it is probably a constant (it often is).